# Parsing Json string into Python Google App Engine Server

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, dictionary

I'm implementing a client server Android app. 
Using a POST request, I'm strucking into parse a Json object sent from client, on the server side.

What I get on the server is:

`{"text":"cccc","type":1}`

and after a json.load() method (passing what I received) I get:

```
{u'type': 1, u'text': u'cccc'}
```

If I try to get values using:

```
 self.value = frase['type']
 self.text = frase['text']
```

I got an error:

```
 string indices must be integers
```

Where I wrong?
Thanks in advance
FB

Comment: `frase = {u'type': 1, u'text': u'cccc'} ;
print frase['type']` — this is working for me. I think your problem is elsewhere.. It's like you already had the value, and started to 'slice' it.

Comment: Something is going wrong with the assignment of 'frase', please show that peice of code aswell.

Comment: Yes, that's curious. Using python by shell, all works good.

Comment: Solved, I was iterating over an object which contained just an object.